# React-charts not updating with data

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs, column-chart

I am new react, and want to display charts in my component, wherein the the data should be populated from the API response.

My sample API response is:

```
{
    "result": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "data1": "1272.00",
            "data2": "1183.00",
            "price": "131.00"
        },
        {
            "data1": "1328.00",
            "data2": "1468.00",
            "price": "132.00"
        },
        {
            "data1": "1829.00",
            "data2": "1445.00",
            "price": "133.00"
        },
        {
            "data1": "1089.00",
            "data2": "968.00",
            "price": "134.00"
        },
        {
            "data1": "16700.00",
            "data2": "20901.00",
            "price": "135.00"
        },
        {
            "data1": "804.00",
            "data2": "1110.00",
            "price": "136.00"
        },
    ]
}
```

I want `price` to be in YAxis and multiple data, i.e., `data1` and `data2` fields on XAxis.

React code: (implementing just one)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import { Chart } from "react-charts";
import axios from "axios";

const qs = require("qs");

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    datelist: [],
    chart_data: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDatesList();
  }

  getDatesList() {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/dateslist/").then(res => {
      if (res.data.result === 1) {
        this.setState({ datelist: res.data.data });
      } else {
        this.setState({ datelist: [] });
      }
    });
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    var dateval = event.target.value;
    axios
      .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/pricedata/`, qs.stringify({ date: dateval }))
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.result === 1) {
          this.setState({
            chart_data: [
              {
                label: "Strike",
                data: res.data.data
              }
            ]
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ chart_data: [] });
        }
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container container_padding">
        <div className="row">
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <select
              className="form-control"
              style={{ width: "120px", marginBottom: "10px" }}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
              {this.state.datelist.map((date, i) => (
                <option value={date} key={i}>
                  {date}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
            <div
              style={{
                width: "400px",
                height: "300px"
              }}
            >
              <Chart
                data={this.state.chart_data}
                series={{ type: "bar" }}
                axes={[
                  { primary: true, type: "ordinal", position: "bottom" },
                  { type: "linear", position: "left", stacked: true }
                ]}
                primaryCursor
                tooltip
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

The state is updated, but chart is not displayed.

Note: I have installed charts library as - `npm i --save react-chartjs-2 chart.js`

What am I missing? How should I correctly populate data that is to be shown?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using react-charts and installed reat-chartjs-2, in order to use react-charts, please install react-charts from npm using npm i -S react-charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into the response found that you are passing data prop to chart as follows:

```
{
    label: "Strike",
    data: [
    {
        "data1": "1272.00",
        "data2": "1183.00",
        "price": "131.00"
    },
    {
        "data1": "1328.00",
        "data2": "1468.00",
        "price": "132.00"
    },
  ]
}
```

which is apparently not correct, in the react-charts doc you can see it accepts the data in the following pattern:

```
 [
    {
      label: "Series 1",
      data: [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 2], [4, 7]]
    },
    {
      label: "Series 2",
      data: [[0, 3], [1, 1], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 4]]
    }
  ]
```

So to make your code work you need to manipulate the response of your API call to match the pattern.

It can be done by changing the following lines of code:

```
handleChange = event => {
    var dateval = event.target.value;
    axios
      .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/pricedata/`, qs.stringify({ date: dateval }))
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.result === 1) {
          this.setState({
            chart_data: [
              {
                label: "Strike",
                data: res.data.data.map(Object.values)
              }
            ]
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ chart_data: [] });
        }
      });
  };
```

Comment: But chart should be shown according the value selected in selectbox, because I need that change parameter

Comment: And also I have tried to put the code in constructor, but it says undefined on the screen

Comment: @ReemaParakh, I have updated the answer please have a look.

Comment: @ReemaParakh Ok, I have again updated the answer please have a look (data: res.data.data.map(Object.values))

Comment: Thanks, It really helped. But it is showing just one bar for the data. Can I have 2bars , 1 for data1 and 2nd for data2 (on Yaxis) and price (on X axis)

Comment: @ReemaParakh, yes you can, please have a look into the example https://react-charts.js.org/examples/mixed-element-types, you can refer to docs over here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-charts.
Please mark the answer to accepted if that helps

Comment: https://react-charts.js.org/examples/mixed-element-types this links says yes it possible, but there is no sample example for this.

Comment: @ReemaParakh, you should probably ask the new question related to that concern, as the current question is not relevant to that answer, please accept the answer, as it seems your issue is solved regarding updating data in chart

Comment: please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54199391/how-to-configure-multiple-bars-on-same-chart-using-react-charts

Comment: @ReemaParakh, sure :-)