# How to configure multiple bars on same chart using react-charts

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I have a react wherein I am able to display the. For this i am using `react-charts` library.

To populate chart data I am making a API call and thereafter updating the state. I want to display multiple values for YAxis.

My sample API response is:

```
{
"result": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "data1": "1272.00",
        "data2": "1183.00",
        "price": "131.00"
    },
    {
        "data1": "1328.00",
        "data2": "1468.00",
        "price": "132.00"
    },
    {
        "data1": "1829.00",
        "data2": "1445.00",
        "price": "133.00"
    },
 ]
}
```

I want data1 and data2 values forYAxis and price for XAxis.

React code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import { Chart } from "react-charts";
import axios from "axios";

const qs = require("qs");

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    datelist: [],
    chart_data: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDatesList();
    axios
      .post(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pricedata/`,
        qs.stringify({ date: "2019-01-11" })
      )
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.result === 1) {
          this.setState({
            chart_data: [
              {
                label: "Strike",
                data: res.data.data.map(Object.values)
              }
            ]
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ chart_data: [] });
        }
      });
  }

  getDatesList() {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/dateslist/").then(res => {
      if (res.data.result === 1) {
        this.setState({ datelist: res.data.data });
      } else {
        this.setState({ datelist: [] });
      }
    });
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    var dateval = event.target.value;
    axios
      .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/pricedata/`, qs.stringify({ date: dateval }))
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.result === 1) {
          this.setState({
            chart_data: [
              {
                label: "Strike",
                data: res.data.data.map(Object.values)
              }
            ]
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ chart_data: [] });
        }
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container container_padding">
        <div className="row">
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <select
              className="form-control"
              style={{ width: "120px", marginBottom: "10px" }}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
              {this.state.datelist.map((date, i) => (
                <option value={date} key={i}>
                  {date}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
            <div
              style={{
                width: "400px",
                height: "300px"
              }}
            >
              <Chart
                data={this.state.chart_data}
                series={{ type: "bar" }}
                axes={[
                  { primary: true, type: "ordinal", position: "bottom" },
                  { type: "linear", position: "left", stacked: true }
                ]}
                primaryCursor
                tooltip
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @FortyTwo My chart displays only one bar which includes all 3values i.e., data1, data2, and price, but I want- the XAxis should have price, YAxis should have data1 and data2 (multiple types)

Comment: @ReemaParakh, answered your question, please have a look and let us know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify following lines:

```
handleChange = event => {
    var dateval = event.target.value;
    axios
      .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/pricedata/`, qs.stringify({ date: dateval }))
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.result === 1) {
          this.setState({
            chart_data: [
              {
                label: "bar1",
                data: res.data.data.map((d) => ({ x: d.price, y: d.data1 })
              },
              {
                label: "bar2",
                data: res.data.data.map((d) => ({ x: d.price, y: d.data2 })
              }
            ]
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ chart_data: [] });
        }
      });
  };
```

and inside render:

```
<Chart
  data={this.state.chart_data}
  series={{ type: 'bar' }}
  axes={[
    { primary: true, position: 'bottom', type: 'ordinal' },
    { position: 'left', type: 'linear', min: 0 },
  ]}
  primaryCursor
  secondaryCursor
  tooltip
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Could you please also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703320/customize-bar-chart-in-reactjs-using-react-charts